# Elasticsearch wait for index status

Tags: elasticsearch

[Cluster health API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html) has parameter `wait_for_status` that (according to documentation) waits for specified **cluster** status. However, I would like to wait for specific **index** to reach some status.

If I use cluster health request with `level=indices` and `index=myindex` will the wait still operate on cluster level? I guess polling the status and continuing after status is reached would have the same effect but is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to use the `health` api for specific indices, as well:

```
GET /_cluster/health/index_name?wait_for_status=green&timeout=10s
```

Comment: So the documentation is wrong? It clearly says that "Will wait (until the timeout provided) until the **status of the cluster** changes to the one provided or better"

Comment: No, the documentation is not wrong. That statement is for `health` api when no index is being used. But, if you use the request that I suggested, it will wait for the status of the index, of course.

Comment: That's good news. I think the documentation should be more clear about this. I got the impression that the index only affects the filtering of the results but not the status wait.

Comment: That's easy to test :-). Create two indices in a one node cluster. Both indices will have `number_of_replicas: 1`. This means they will be `yellow`, and the cluster will be `yellow`.  Then run the `/_cluster/health/index_name?wait_for_status=green&timeout=100s`. In a separate windows, run `PUT /index_name/_settings
{
  "index": { 
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  }
}`.This will change the number of replicas to 0 from 1, which will instantly make that specific index go `green`. Then you will see the first command return. Even if the cluster is still `yellow` from the other index that has 1 replica